# How to customize one of the standard Google Maps API map types

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-engine

There are 2 options for base map in Earth Engine: `Map` (default) and `Satellite`. I would like to have `Satellite` as default base map when I press `ctrl + enter` (or click `run` button). I know that I can switch between the 2 options by clicking on the desired one, but I would like to make this automatic.

I tried:

```
Map.setOptions({
  mapTypeId: "SATELLITE"
});
```

This almost does what I want expect that all labels and countries / administrative boundaries are turned off. How can I have both the satellite base map and these features?

I checked [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/customizing-base-map-styles#changing_the_basic_map_style), but I can't figure out how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```
Map.setOptions('HYBRID')
```

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/map-setoptions

Comment: Thanks, that got me what I want. BTW, I confess that I haven't tried these options (i.e. "SATELLITE", "HYBRID" or "TERRAIN") before posting the question. Are they documented somewhere? It would be good if I can manipulation things, for examples, remove labels and keep the boundaries.